# Inner product of integral with partial derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, inner-products

I have the norm and the inner product
\begin{align}
\|u(x)\|^2&=\int_a^b |u(x)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x,\\
\left<u(x),v(x)\right>&=\int_a^b u(x)v(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
Why can this integral be written as
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega u(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d} \|u(x,t)\|^2}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{align}
Also, why no partial derivative in the RHS?

Comment: Note that $u\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial t}$. Then move the differential outside the integral sign (as the integration region does not depend on $t$) and use the definition to get the result (alternatively work backwards from the RHS using [Leibnitz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to move the differential inside the integral). Why no partial derivatives; well notation is not always consistently used. In this case it does not matter as $x$ does not depend on $t$ so the partial derivative is the same as the normal derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The expression as written in the OP is not quite correct.  If $u\in \mathbb{C}$, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d||u||^2(t)}{dt}&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b |u(x,t)|^2\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u(x,t)\,\overline{u}(x,t))\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b \left(u(x,t)\frac{\partial \overline{u}(x,t)}{\partial t}+\overline{u}(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}\right)\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

If $u\in \mathbb{R}$, then $(1)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d||u||^2(t)}{dt}&=2\int_a^b u(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

The reason that the total derivative appears outside the integral while the partial derivative appears inside the integral is that the integration of $|u(x,t)|^2$ is over the dummy variable $x$.  Hence, $||u||^2(t)$ is only a function of $t$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark